# OpenGL ES 2.0 severe FPS drop on glDrawArrays

Tags: android, debugging, opengl-es, live-wallpaper, frame-rate

I am working with a simple OpenGL ES 2.0 app, more specifically I am working on a live wallpaper utilizing GLWallpaperService.  I've managed to get a good ways into it thanks to a lot of help from the StackOverflow community (Thanks guys!), but I seem to be running into a bit of a performance issue even though it is still very simplistic.

Right now, as far as drawing goes, I am only drawing four triangle strips to the screen and applying a texture to each.  While I'm sure it is not ideal, I figured it would be fine to do this with four separate calls to glDrawArrays, but apparently this operation is much more taxing than I imagined.  Those four draw calls alone seem to be cutting the FPS of my wallpaper on my Droid X by over half, from 60 down to the mid 20's.

While I don't want to me rendering a wallpaper at max FPS for obvious reasons, having this extreme drop in this early stage when I am only drawing four triangle strips is unacceptable.  There will be quite a bit more drawing going on, including a particle system, in the final version and I cannot move on until I have my performance under control.

I have not looked into VBO's very much as I didn't think I needed to yet, but they sound like what I should be going for in this situation.  Are they really required even for such simple draw calls?  I also read a while back that they have issues with certain phones, but I believe this only applied to older phones, which doesn't apply to me since I will require OpenGL ES 2.0 as well as Live Wallpaper support.

Also, to sneak another question in here, I am unable to enable debugging in order to see what exactly is happening with my wallpaper.  My manifest is set properly, and after a quick search I added the line :

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

To my code, but it will never attach and simply leave my wallpaper black while it waits (forever).  This is certainly a bit of a problem when monitoring performance is so essential for things like live wallpapers, so bonus kudos for any insight on this one as well.

**EDIT ::**  Here is my current fragment shader.  This is pretty cobbled together, just to make things work for the time being, and has some bugs relating to other parts of my app, but I don't see it causing my issues.

```
        final String fragmentShader =           
        "precision mediump float;       \n"     
        + "varying vec2 v_Color;          \n"     
        + "uniform sampler2D s_baseMap;   \n"
        + "uniform vec4 u_Color;   \n"
        + "void main()                    \n"     
        + "{                              \n"
        + "  vec4 baseColor = texture2D( s_baseMap, v_Color );   \n"
        + "  vec4 colorAdd1 = vec4(u_Color);    \n"
        + "  if(baseColor.a > 0.0){     \n"
        + "     if(baseColor.a < 0.5){     \n"
        + "        baseColor.a = 0.0;        \n"
        + "      } else {                         \n"
        + "      baseColor = (baseColor + colorAdd1);  \n"
        + "      }                            \n"
        + "   }                            \n"
        + "  gl_FragColor = baseColor;     \n"    
        + "}                              \n";
```

I am "colorizing" my textures programatically for customization purposes, which is what the "u_Color" vector represents.  The mess about checking the textures alpha is to prevent it from just applying the color to every pixel and only doing it on the 'solid' ones.  I did remove that part once to see the result to my FPS, and while it did indeed increase, it was only seemed to be by a small amount of 3-5FPS.

**EDIT ::** I was just doing a little testing via log messages and it seems as though nothing in my "onDraw" method is creating my problem.  If I log something at the very beginning of my onDraw method, and then something else at the very end after all of my drawing and everything, they both log almost instantaneously every time, certainly not enough to cause the huge gaps I am experiencing.  Unless this is some fault of the log system, then I have to be getting these lags in framerate elsewhere.

With my current knowledge of OpenGL ES 2.0, this seems quite baffling to me.  I was lead to believe that once it got around to the onDraw method, it would continuously run in that method like a loop up until some state change, such as changing orientation and calling onSurfaceChanged.  If what I described above is not a bug in the way the logcat handles things, then it must leave this loop and go somewhere that is bogging me down.

The only explanation I can think of for this is that the GLWallpaperService setup that I am using in order to use OpenGL ES 2.0 in live wallpapers is to blame.  Unfortunately, unless I can get debug working on this to show me exactly where the slow down is happening, I am not sure how I would be able to find and (hopefully) fix it, so it seems not being able to use the debugging tools is the biggest problem for me.

Comment: glDrawArrays is near instantaneous because it doesn't actually draw anything. It adds the primitives to the beginning of the pipeline and returns. The GPU then draws in parallel with the CPU.

Comment: The time spent outside of your draw call is probably in eglSwapBuffers, which may block if the GPU is still working on a previous frame.

Comment: I had just figured it was something in my own code, rather than the GLWallpaperService code I am using, which tries to take care of a lot of the work including the eglSwapBuffers.  I did find the call to eglSwapBuffers, but after a bit of testing I can't seem to find any noticeable delay coming from there either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VBOs/VAOs are required for OpenGL ES as the fixed function stuff is not supported anymore in this version (glBegin/End).

Hard to say where the problem is, without some code. But it certainly shouldn't be that way. (I have no android phone)
But i can post some links...
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html (i prefer this)
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html  (you can also try this)

Comment: Well, since it is better to use VBO's anyway I will work on getting that going.  Is it normal for my live wallpaper to experience such a severe slow down from only four glDrawArray calls though?  Or is it perhaps the result of something else in my code?  Unfortunately my code is an absolute mess of epic proportions at the moment, but I could try and make pieces of it semi-presentable if anybody has any idea where such an issue may be.  I'd like to keep this project as efficient and "properly" coded as possible.

Comment: glBegin/glEnd isn't fixed function, it is compatible with shaders too. But they are not present in ES.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're drawing some very large vertex arrays, the glDrawArray call probably isn't the problem. The problem is more likely either the calls you're making alongside glDrawArray, or what's happening in your fragment shader. For example, if you're filling the entire screen 4 times with blending and sampling from 2048x2048 textures, or if you're recompiling your shaders every time, a drop to 20 fps would be expected.

Comment: Well if the images aren't being drawn, either because I remove the glDrawArrays call or I get rid of a few lines relating to the matrices that keep everything positioned, it will go back up to 60 FPS.  All four of the images are being stored in a 1024x1024 texture atlas (They don't fill it completely, that's just what I had to use to fit them in a power of 2 texture).  If I disable blending, resulting in the textures losing their alpha, the FPS goes up to 50FPS (Which is still lower than I would like at such an early stage, even with everything working properly.)

Comment: If blending or not blending makes a difference of 20 vs 50 fps, your problem is certainly with pixel fill. Try drawing the triangles at a much smaller size (like 2x2px) and see how it affects performance.

Comment: Seems you're correct.  I am using triangle strips to create quads to apply the textures to, and the smaller I make these on the screen the higher my FPS seems to go.  Is this likely the cause of a small error somewhere, or perhaps I misunderstood some of the fundamentals (as I am learning as I go along here) and did something entirely wrong to begin with?

Comment: Chances are you're simply hitting a limit with the GPU. Which device are you developing on? How many pixels are you trying to fill each frame? What does your fragment shader look like? Keep in mind that for a live wallpaper you have to share the GPU with both the Launcher and SurfaceFlinger, so you hit limits much much sooner.

Comment: I am using a Droid X for testing right now, which I've done some pretty intensive things with and don't imagine if I was doing things properly that texturing four sets of triangles would hurt it so badly, even as a live wallpaper.  I will post the fragment shader I am using in the main post, though it's a bit thrown together at the moment, but nothing about it seems terribly off based on other examples I have looked at.

Comment: Was just doing a little bit of testing via logging and the results have me a bit confused, I'll type up a proper description in the main post (can't make it all fit here).